# Please advise how can I create Multi-Host Private Blockchain Network

Tags: nodeos

Because I would like to deploy Private Blockchain like Diagram below.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI59D.jpg)

But Document have only method for setup Multi-Node on Single Host

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/local-multi-node-testnet

Moreover I tried to understand this Document but I'm not sure that's the right solution for build node on multiple servers or not. When I look at method for create genesis.json files. It seem not clear about EOS_PUB_DEV_KEY that Should I use Public Key from another server or not? (Example : use Public Key of Server 2 in genesis.json file on Server 1).

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence

Please advise solution or guideline for me, Thank you very much.![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually recommend trying the local multi-node testnet as well. Its a good learning process in general, getting used to cleos and such

For the boot sequence and genesis.json file. genesis.json for all nodes in a certain testnet should share the same genesis.json file at launch, otherwise they don't recognize each other as the part of the same chain. You can choose any key that you want to use, but make sure that key is included as eosio for the booting sequence as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I will try again. However I hove that EOS should have official document for this scenario in the future.